# Python3 Inline if and for statements

Tags: python-3.x

```
def interseccion(lista1, lista2):
    return [x if x in lista2 for x in lista1] // Syntax error here (1)
    #~ return [x for x in lista1 if x in lista2] // A way I found searching that works)

print(interseccion([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,3,5]))
```

So, I've tried to find Python's Documentation on that kind of expressions and couldn't find it.

It seems that `x if x in lista2` expects always an `else` but I don't need it. Using `else pass` doesn't work either.

I would like to get some links to the docs where these kind of expressions are explained.... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to write:

```
return [x for x in lista1 if x in lista2]
```

These are called [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: If the order doesn't matter and the items are hashable: `set(list1).intersection(list2)`